# PIG Job fails when using ISOHoursBetween() UDF

Tags: apache-pig

I have the Pig script failing when using the ISOYearsBetween() API of Piggybank along with DUMP statement. However the DESCRIBE command works ok.
The Piggybank jar is loaded properly as CustomFormatToISO() works fine .

Below is the script and log.

```
Register piggybank.jar
Register joda-time-1.6.jar
DEFINE ISOYearsBetween org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.diff.ISOYearsBetween();
DEFINE CustomFormatToISO org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.CustomFormatToISO();
DEFINE ISOHoursBetween org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.diff.ISOHoursBetween();

daily = load '/user/hue/pig/examples/actio/status.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage() as
(cust_ref:chararray,event_code:chararray,event_date:chararray,event_time:chararray,depot:chararray,event_status:chararray);
status = filter daily by cust_ref != '"Consignment_No"';
refined = foreach status generate cust_ref,CustomFormatToISO(event_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as date, CustomFormatToISO(event_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as time,depot,event_status;
diffs = FOREACH refined GENERATE cust_ref,ISOHoursBetween(time,date) AS Hours;
describe diffs;
dump diffs;


LogsApache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.4.0 (rexported) 
compiled Sep 03 2013, 10:53:34

Run pig script using PigRunner.run() for Pig version 0.8+
2014-03-12 07:57:06,775 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main  - Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.4.0 (rexported) compiled Sep 03 2013, 10:53:34
2014-03-12 07:57:06,775 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main  - Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.4.0 (rexported) compiled Sep 03 2013, 10:53:34
2014-03-12 07:57:06,787 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main  - Logging error messages to: /mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201403120637_0013/attempt_201403120637_0013_m_000000_0/work/pig-job_201403120637_0013.log
2014-03-12 07:57:06,787 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main  - Logging error messages to: /mapred/local/taskTracker/cloudera/jobcache/job_201403120637_0013/attempt_201403120637_0013_m_000000_0/work/pig-job_201403120637_0013.log
2014-03-12 07:57:06,916 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.df.interval is deprecated. Instead, use fs.df.interval
2014-03-12 07:57:06,916 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.max.objects is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.max.objects
2014-03-12 07:57:06,916 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
2014-03-12 07:57:06,916 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.data.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.data.dir
2014-03-12 07:57:06,916 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.name.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.name.dir
2014-03-12 07:57:06,916 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-03-12 07:57:06,917 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - fs.checkpoint.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir
2014-03-12 07:57:06,917 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.block.size is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.blocksize
2014-03-12 07:57:06,917 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.access.time.precision is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.accesstime.precision
2014-03-12 07:57:06,917 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.replication.min is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.replication.min
2014-03-12 07:57:06,917 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.name.edits.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.edits.dir
2014-03-12 07:57:06,917 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.replication.considerLoad is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.replication.considerLoad
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.balance.bandwidthPerSec is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.balance.bandwidthPerSec
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.safemode.threshold.pct is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.http-address
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.name.dir.restore is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.name.dir.restore
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.https.client.keystore.resource is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.client.https.keystore.resource
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.backup.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.backup.address
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.backup.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.backup.http-address
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.permissions is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.permissions.enabled
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.safemode.extension is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.safemode.extension
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.datanode.max.xcievers is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.max.transfer.threads
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.https.need.client.auth is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.client.https.need-auth
2014-03-12 07:57:06,918 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.https.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.https-address
2014-03-12 07:57:06,919 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.replication.interval is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.replication.interval
2014-03-12 07:57:06,919 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - fs.checkpoint.edits.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.checkpoint.edits.dir
2014-03-12 07:57:06,919 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.write.packet.size is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.client-write-packet-size
2014-03-12 07:57:06,919 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.permissions.supergroup is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.permissions.superusergroup
2014-03-12 07:57:06,919 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - topology.script.number.args is deprecated. Instead, use net.topology.script.number.args
2014-03-12 07:57:06,919 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.umaskmode is deprecated. Instead, use fs.permissions.umask-mode
2014-03-12 07:57:06,919 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - dfs.secondary.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address
2014-03-12 07:57:06,919 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - fs.checkpoint.period is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period
2014-03-12 07:57:06,919 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - topology.node.switch.mapping.impl is deprecated. Instead, use net.topology.node.switch.mapping.impl
2014-03-12 07:57:06,924 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
2014-03-12 07:57:06,937 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils  - Default bootup file /usr/lib/hadoop/.pigbootup not found
2014-03-12 07:57:06,937 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils  - Default bootup file /usr/lib/hadoop/.pigbootup not found
2014-03-12 07:57:07,079 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-03-12 07:57:07,079 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine  - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020
2014-03-12 07:57:07,079 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine  - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020
2014-03-12 07:57:07,081 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
2014-03-12 07:57:07,089 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine  - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: localhost.localdomain:8021
2014-03-12 07:57:07,089 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine  - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: localhost.localdomain:8021
diffs: {cust_ref: chararray,Hours: long}
2014-03-12 07:57:08,044 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState  - Pig features used in the script: FILTER
2014-03-12 07:57:08,044 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState  - Pig features used in the script: FILTER
2014-03-12 07:57:08,131 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.ColumnPruneVisitor  - Columns pruned for daily: $1, $4, $5
2014-03-12 07:57:08,131 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.ColumnPruneVisitor  - Columns pruned for daily: $1, $4, $5
2014-03-12 07:57:08,356 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler  - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2014-03-12 07:57:08,356 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler  - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2014-03-12 07:57:08,438 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer  - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2014-03-12 07:57:08,438 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer  - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2014-03-12 07:57:08,438 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer  - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2014-03-12 07:57:08,438 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer  - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2014-03-12 07:57:08,590 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl  - falling back to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.23 ?)
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: jobsInProgress
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1882)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.<clinit>(PigJobControl.java:58)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.newJobControl(HadoopShims.java:102)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:285)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:177)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1266)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1251)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:933)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:900)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:696)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:320)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:475)
    at org.apache.pig.PigRunner.run(PigRunner.java:49)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.runPigJob(PigMain.java:283)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.run(PigMain.java:223)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.main(PigMain.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
2014-03-12 07:57:08,590 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl  - falling back to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.23 ?)
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: jobsInProgress
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1882)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.<clinit>(PigJobControl.java:58)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.newJobControl(HadoopShims.java:102)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:285)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:177)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1266)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1251)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:933)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:900)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:696)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:320)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:475)
    at org.apache.pig.PigRunner.run(PigRunner.java:49)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.runPigJob(PigMain.java:283)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.run(PigMain.java:223)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.main(PigMain.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
2014-03-12 07:57:08,604 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState  - Pig script settings are added to the job
2014-03-12 07:57:08,604 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState  - Pig script settings are added to the job
2014-03-12 07:57:08,627 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2014-03-12 07:57:08,627 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2014-03-12 07:57:08,643 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - Using reducer estimator: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator
2014-03-12 07:57:08,643 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - Using reducer estimator: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator
2014-03-12 07:57:08,650 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator  - BytesPerReducer=1000000000 maxReducers=999 totalInputFileSize=12120523
2014-03-12 07:57:08,650 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator  - BytesPerReducer=1000000000 maxReducers=999 totalInputFileSize=12120523
2014-03-12 07:57:08,650 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - Setting Parallelism to 1
2014-03-12 07:57:08,650 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - Setting Parallelism to 1
2014-03-12 07:57:08,964 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - creating jar file Job3418500970455913591.jar
2014-03-12 07:57:08,964 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - creating jar file Job3418500970455913591.jar
2014-03-12 07:57:11,824 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - jar file Job3418500970455913591.jar created
2014-03-12 07:57:11,824 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - jar file Job3418500970455913591.jar created
2014-03-12 07:57:11,849 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - Setting up single store job
2014-03-12 07:57:11,849 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler  - Setting up single store job
2014-03-12 07:57:11,862 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend  - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2014-03-12 07:57:11,862 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend  - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2014-03-12 07:57:11,862 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend  - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2014-03-12 07:57:11,862 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend  - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2014-03-12 07:57:11,862 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend  - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2014-03-12 07:57:11,862 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend  - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2014-03-12 07:57:11,925 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2014-03-12 07:57:11,925 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2014-03-12 07:57:11,960 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient  - Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
2014-03-12 07:57:12,320 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat  - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-03-12 07:57:12,320 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil  - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-03-12 07:57:12,320 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil  - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-03-12 07:57:12,327 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil  - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
2014-03-12 07:57:12,327 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil  - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
2014-03-12 07:57:12,431 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - 0% complete
2014-03-12 07:57:12,431 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - 0% complete
2014-03-12 07:57:12,981 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - HadoopJobId: job_201403120637_0014
2014-03-12 07:57:12,981 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - HadoopJobId: job_201403120637_0014
2014-03-12 07:57:12,981 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - Processing aliases daily,diffs,refined,status
2014-03-12 07:57:12,981 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - Processing aliases daily,diffs,refined,status
2014-03-12 07:57:12,981 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - detailed locations: M: daily[7,8],daily[-1,-1],status[9,9],refined[10,10],diffs[11,8] C:  R: 
2014-03-12 07:57:12,981 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - detailed locations: M: daily[7,8],daily[-1,-1],status[9,9],refined[10,10],diffs[11,8] C:  R: 
2014-03-12 07:57:12,982 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - More information at: http://localhost.localdomain:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201403120637_0014
2014-03-12 07:57:12,982 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - More information at: http://localhost.localdomain:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201403120637_0014
Heart beat
2014-03-12 07:57:52,679 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2014-03-12 07:57:52,679 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2014-03-12 07:57:52,679 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - job job_201403120637_0014 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2014-03-12 07:57:52,679 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - job job_201403120637_0014 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2014-03-12 07:57:52,680 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - 100% complete
2014-03-12 07:57:52,680 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - 100% complete
2014-03-12 07:57:52,686 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats  - ERROR: null
2014-03-12 07:57:52,686 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats  - ERROR: null
2014-03-12 07:57:52,686 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil  - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2014-03-12 07:57:52,686 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil  - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2014-03-12 07:57:52,693 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats  - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0  0.11.0-cdh4.4.0 mapred  2014-03-12 07:57:08 2014-03-12 07:57:52 FILTER

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201403120637_0014   daily,diffs,refined,status  MAP_ONLY    Message: Job failed!    hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/tmp/temp1404625512/tmp649311321,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/user/hue/pig/examples/actio/status.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/tmp/temp1404625512/tmp649311321"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201403120637_0014


2014-03-12 07:57:52,693 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats  - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0  0.11.0-cdh4.4.0 mapred  2014-03-12 07:57:08 2014-03-12 07:57:52 FILTER

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201403120637_0014   daily,diffs,refined,status  MAP_ONLY    Message: Job failed!    hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/tmp/temp1404625512/tmp649311321,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/user/hue/pig/examples/actio/status.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/tmp/temp1404625512/tmp649311321"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201403120637_0014


2014-03-12 07:57:52,693 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - Failed!
2014-03-12 07:57:52,693 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher  - Failed!
2014-03-12 07:57:52,720 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias diffs. Backend error : null
2014-03-12 07:57:52,720 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias diffs. Backend error : null
Hadoop Job IDs executed by Pig: job_201403120637_0014
```

**EDITED**
I checked the job and its a null pointer exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.diff.ISOHoursBetween.exec(ISOHoursBetween.java:95)
at org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.diff.ISOHoursBetween.exec(ISOHoursBetween.java:83)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:337)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:416)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:348)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:372)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNext(POForEach.java:297)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:283)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduc
```

However when I dump the output of CustomFormatoISO() it appears fine.
 I dont understand why its causing an NULL pointer exception when output of **CustomFormatoISO**() is passed to **ISOHoursBetween**().
*Passing hardcoded values to ISOHoursBetween() works fine.*

Below is DUMP( which looks ok , hence puzzling as to why I get a NULL exception ) taken after calling CustomFormatISO()

```
(2013-01-11T00:00:00.000Z,1899-12-30T19:40:00.000Z,Hub 3 - Birmingham,Confirmed at Hub)
(2013-01-14T00:00:00.000Z,1899-12-30T04:36:00.000Z,London Bridge,Confirmed)
```

Comment: Just to confirm ... the path to the file really is "/user/hue/pig/examples/actio/status.csv", and not "/user/hue/pig/examples/action/status.csv"

Comment: Yes the path is correct :)

Comment: That's curious ... I notice you're using the CDH 4.4 Quickstart VM, which I have a copy of up and running on a dev environment.  Is the example dataset you're using available for download so I can test it locally?

Comment: Managed to solve the issue. It was due to my Header field getting included which had NULL values for the Date field.